# Access token expired in at time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, token

How to know that my token has expired?

I know `"expires_at":"1536918137"`

- What does it number mean?
- How to convert it into datetime or how to compare it with the current time in javascript and know that token expired or not?

Comment: it is probably in milliseconds,

Answer (score 2):

It's in unix time which is the seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC). Try this converter https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: `date -ud '@1536918137'` works also if you have a Linux computer handy. According to `date` command that timestamp is Friday Sep 14 09:42:17 UTC 2018. Remove `-u` switch to get time in your time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools https://unixtime.org/